# Python code for this algorithm to identify outliers in k-means clustering

Tags: python, k-means

The have an `input_df` which has stirng index and not integers.
The index could be anything like '1234a', 'abcd', and so on.

I have performed k-means on an input df with `k = 100` and have received `centroid` and `labels` as output.

If I am not wrong,

- the `centroid` has 100 values corresponding to the mean of all points within a cluster for 100 such clusters.
- `labels` has the same size as that of the `input_df` which shows which cluster does that point/row belongs to.

I have to now perform a process to identify the outliers in k-means clustering as per the following pseudo-code.

```
c_x : corresponding centroid of sample point x where x ∈ X

1. Compute the l2 distance of every point to its corresponding centroid.
2. t = the 0.05 or 95% percentile of the l2 distances.
3. for each sample point x in X do
4.     if || x - c_x ||2 > t then 
5.          mark x as outlier
```

Note: the `2` in line 4 is a subscript.

Now, I do not completely understand the condition mentioned in line 4.

Can someone give an equivalent Python code for the above-mentioned algorithm?

Here is the structure of the code.

```
def remove_outliers(input_df, centroids, labels):
    pass

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=100)
kmeans.fit(input_df)
centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
labels = kmeans.labels_


filtered_centroids, filtered_labels = remove_outliers(input_df, centroids, labels)
```

Answer (score 1):

This algorithm is poorly written, and it is very difficult to understand. However, here is what I think was most likely meant by the algorithm:

1. Compute the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#Two_dimensions) between each point in X and its corresponding centroid c_x.
2. Compute the 95th [percentile](https://www.dummies.com/article/academics-the-arts/math/statistics/how-to-calculate-percentiles-in-statistics-169783/) of the Euclidean distances obtained in Step 1. This will serve as the threshold to determine which points in X will be outliers.
3. For each point in X, if the corresponding Euclidean distance obtained in Step 1 is greater than the threshold obtained in Step 2, mark the point as an outlier.

The algorithm wants you to calculate the Euclidean distance again for Steps 3-5, even though it has already been done in Step 1. You probably do not want to do that. If you are using Pandas DataFrame, perhaps you could store X, c_x, and the Euclidean distance calculations in the same DataFrame and loop it over.

I will leave it to you to implement this in Python.

P.S. I am assuming that the notations `L₂` distance and `||x||₂` both mean the Euclidean distance, as mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)).

Comment: I agree that the algorithm is very confusing and the notations are unclear. I will try to implement it as per your answer. Can you consider upvoting the question so it is non-negative?